# UTXO Workshop: how to get Alice's sigscript?

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot-js

This might be a stupid question...

I was playing around the [utxo-workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuJmxMMHvDw&lc=UgwFncXo12Z6ald8n2N4AaABAg), and there's a comment below asking on how to get alice's sigscript.

I tried following the procedure in the test cases found in [`utxo.rs`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/utxo-workshop/blob/master/runtime/src/utxo.rs#L431):

```rust
let alice_signature = sp_io::crypto::sr25519_sign(SR25519, &alice_pub_key, &transaction.encode()).unwrap();
transaction.inputs[0].sigscript = H512::from(alice_signature);
```

But it returns an error: `` called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value ``.

I'm guessing the Transaction should look like this:

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "outpoint": "0x76584168d10a20084082ed80ec71e2a783abbb8dd6eb9d4893b089228498e9ff",
      "sigscript": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "value": 50,
      "pubkey": "0x8eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a48"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get the Alice Signature on a transaction where she spends 50 utxo on Bob:
`0x6ceab99702c60b111c12c2867679c5555c00dcd4d6ab40efa01e3a65083bfb6c6f5c1ed3356d7141ec61894153b8ba7fb413bf1e990ed99ff6dee5da1b24fd83`?

Or how can I do it in [polkadot.js](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/signing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, basically I just used the [`Pair` to sign the transaction inside the `chain_spec.rs` of the node module](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L19).

And also just did it literally outside the project, from the [polkascan](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#keypair-creation-and-signing).